# Scrolling through all color combinations on a vertical column of pixels

Tags: java, graphics, colors, rgb, pixel

I'm trying to scroll through every single RGB color combination possible on a vertical set of pixels. In this example assume that the pixel column is 1080. I understand that all possible combinations amount to approximately 18 billion at that number. I can't seem to wrap my head around the loop structure. I have the loop for figuring all color combinations for one pixel here.

```
for(int r = 0;r < 256;r++){
    for(int g = 0;g < 256;g++){
        for(int b = 0;b < 256;b++){
            pixelC =
            Integer.toString(r)+":"+
            Integer.toString(g)+":"+
            Integer.toString(b)+";";
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need something that can apply the pixel color to the column. I'm just not sure how to work out the logic of doing this because I have to apply the color in all possible combinations. So having a vertical strip of all white with a vertical strip of all black is not my goal. Rather a sporadic peppering of pixels in all possible combinations.

Comment: How could you use all possible combinations assuming the height of the graphic is not 256^3 pixels tall? Or Do you want to distinct set of colors in a given column? Not clear what you are asking.

Comment: 256 cubed is all possible colors for 1 pixel. What I need to do is apply all colors to every pixel in a vertical column in every possible combination. That ends up being 1080 X 256^3. We are assuming in this example that the graphic is 1080 pixels tall but it could really be any number.

Comment: At any given point in time, do you want all 1080 pixels to be distinct or can some colors be repeated? I know you said you don't want them all the same color (i.e. 1 strip of black or white), but what about the case where 540 pixels would be @ (255,255,255) and the other 540 @ (0,0,0). What is your duplicate color tolerance here?

Comment: Yes I would like colors to be repeated. Literally every combination. That repetition is what's really throwing me off

Comment: Please see my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish is too difficult and cumbersome with for loops.

Basically, you are trying to count in base `256^3 = 16,777,216`. And with a column height of 1080, the number of combinations is **astronomical**!

```
(256^3)^1080 ≈ 4.983 × 10^7802
```

Let me explain with a simplified example. Instead of a column height of 1080, let's say it is of height 4. And instead of having 16,777,216 different color combinations for each pixel, say we only have 10 different color combinations.

Furthermore, instead of color values being composed of RGB, let's say each color can have a value from 0-9. In this example, the column (of 4 pixels) can be in `10^4 = 10,000` different states.

Let's visualize this: Think about the column being on its side so it is horizontal and let's treat it like it's one of those combination locks with dials that can spin from 0-9.

This would be the initial state (All 4 dials/pixels at color = 0):

```
-------------------------
|  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
-------------------------
```

This would be the final state (All 4 dials/pixels at color = 9):

```
-------------------------
|  9  |  9  |  9  |  9  |
-------------------------
```

In your case, you would have a combination lock that has 1080 dials and each dial can spin from 0-16,777,215

Now, I was interested in how I can simplify the code so that you don't have to have 1080 for loops or n for loops in the general case where n is the height of the column.

Here's what I came up with:

```
// This represents the combination lock with 4 dials
int [] arr = new int [4];

// This represents how many states each dial can be in
int base = 10; // (0-9)

boolean done = false;

while (!done)
{
    // just for printing out the current state of the array
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

    int index = 0;

    // get to the first dial that has not reached its max value
    while (index < arr.length && arr[index] == base - 1)
    {
        index++;
    }

    // all dials are at the max value -> we are done
    if (index == arr.length)
    {
        done = true;
    }
    else
    {
        // increase the first dial we found to not have a max value
        arr[index]++;

        // set all dials before it to 0
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = 0;
        }
    }           
}
```

**Note**: This algorithm increases the values from left to right. I figured this made sense in adapting it to actual problem with a column in a graphic since you would start changing colors from the top down vs. bottom up. If you want colors to start changing from the bottom up, then it can easily be adapted by changing the indices, increments to decrements, etc.

Now, this example is for simple integer values and int arrays. How can we adapt it to your problem with colors?

First, let's assume that the column slice is an array of `java.awt.Color`

That is, `int [] arr = new int [4];` becomes `Color [] arr = new Color [4];`

Next, instead of `int base = 10; // (0-9)` we would have `int base = 16777216; // (0-16,777,215)`

Now, the rest of the code is pretty much the same except we have to adapt a few things:

This:

```
while (index < arr.length && arr[index] == base - 1)
{
    index++;
}
```

Needs to become this:

```
while (index < arr.length && arr[index].equals(Color.WHITE))
{
    index++;
}
```

This:

```
// increase the first dial we found to not have a max value
arr[index]++;
```

Needs to become this:

```
// increase the first color we found to not have a max value
Color current = arr[index];
arr[index] = new Color(current.getRGB() + 1);
```

Lastly, for this portion:

```
// set all dials before it to 0
for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
{
    arr[i] = 0;
}
```

We can simply do:

```
// set all colors before it to 0
for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
{
    arr[i] = Color.BLACK;
}
```

Also, keep in mind you will need to initialize the Color array. This can be done like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    arr[i] = Color.BLACK;
}
```

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I was looking for. I'd thought the for loop model would've been insufficient but i'd no knowledge of an alternative. Thank you very much.